# issue enabling a drupal module using drush

Tags: drupal-modules, drush, drupal-9

I am facing issues enabling ckeditor iframe module in my drupal9 project.

installed drush using composer

```
composer require drush/drush
```

and used composer to install ckeditor iframe module

```
 composer require 'drupal/ckeditor_iframe
```

but when i tried to enable it using

```
./vendor/bin/drush en ckeditor_iframe
```

my terminal gave me error

```
Error: Undefined constant PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY in Drupal\mysql\Driver\Database\mysql\Connection::open() (line 172 of /opt/lampp/htdocs/piy_drupal/web/core/modules/mysql/src/Driver/Database/mysql/Connection.php).
 [warning] Drush command terminated abnormally.
```

i was expecting it to enable the module for me to configure on my drupal9 project

Comment: Sonuds like `pdo_mysql` is not enabled?

Comment: yes, thanks i enabled it and now my issue is resolved